# Rails + SSL error: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu. I'm having an issue connecting to another server in one of my `http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)` calls. This seemed to be pretty helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728436/opensslsslsslerror-ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-c

I think one of the answers will work for me:

`On my Ubuntu install I had to set export SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`

However, I am unsure what he means by setting export to SSL_CERT etc... Where do I put that line? In my .bashrc / .profile ? And as which user?

Answer (score 0):

export is used to set environment variables. the command above creates (or updates) the variable SSL_CERT_FILE with the specified path, put it in your .profile.